# Simplest way to interact with a Python script that is called by another program?

Tags: python

I have a Python script `client.py` that is called when I start my `server.py` (I cannot change this).

I want the `client.py` script to interact with the user, i.e., ask for input and show output, but as the `client.py` script has been called by the server, I cannot interact with it via console.

I'd like to know what is the simplest approach to asking for input from the `client.py` script, given that I cannot input to STDIN. I imagine two different approaches:

- Using a GUI (like TKinter). But I would have to move all my script into a thread because the main loop of the GUI will want to be on the main thread.
- Using sockets and connecting either via terminal or webpage. But this feels like an overkill.

Is there any simpler option I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `client.py` temporarily override `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` with the system's console device whenever it needs to input from or output to the console, and restore `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` afterwards. In UNIX-like systems, the console device is `/dev/tty`, and in Windows, it is `con`.

For example, with a `client.py` like:

```
import sys

original_stdin = sys.stdin
original_stdout = sys.stdout
console_device = 'con' if sys.platform.startswith('win') else '/dev/tty'

def user_print(*args, **kwargs):
    sys.stdout = open(console_device, 'w')
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout

def user_input(prompt=''):
    user_print(prompt, end='')
    sys.stdin = open(console_device)
    value = input('')
    sys.stdin = original_stdin
    return value

user_print('Server says:', input())
print(user_input('Enter something for the server: '), end='')
```

and a `server.py` like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('python client.py', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8', shell=True)
output, _ = p.communicate('Hello client\n')
print('Client says:', output)
```

you can interact with `server.py` like:

```
Server says: Hello client
Enter something for the server: hi
Client says: hi
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/CheeryEnchantingNasm

Comment: Thank you! I'd forgotten about pipes. I'll try this out. I am considering this the right answer because I believe it's the simplest choice.